# boto3 dynamodb PutItem with reserved word

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

i want to store some data to dynamodb table which has this primary key

```
partition key: invocationId
sort key: index
```

at the moment of using boto3 to PutItem the following error show up:

```
An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the PutItem operation: Invalid ConditionExpression: Attribute name is a reserved keyword; reserved keyword: index
```

and indeed, `index` is part of reserved words list :(
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ReservedWords.html

i tried the following code using `ExpressionAttributeNames`:

```py
self._table.put_item(
    Item={
        '#I': entity.index,
        'invocationId': entity.invocationId,
        ...
    },
    ExpressionAttributeNames={
        '#I': 'index'
    },
)
```

but it raises:

```
An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the PutItem operation: ExpressionAttributeNames can only be specified when using expressions
```

it's worth to mention that .net client works ok for the same use case, because i have put some records with `index` as sort key in that same table, but now it is required to use this table from python and boto3.

this is how it works in .net

```cs
AmazonDynamoDBClient DynamoClient = new AmazonDynamoDBClient();
var _table = Table.LoadTable(DynamoClient, "my-table-name");
var d = new Document()
            {
                ["invocationId"] = "...",
                ["index"] = "...",
            };
d.Add("newParam", "value");
d.Add(...);
_table.UpdateItemAsync(d).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

after this snippet execution, index column is populated correctly! so after all, it is possible.

Comment: Its super inconvenient to have the `index` name I think :D Hope you solve your problem man

Answer (score 3):

You used the right solution - `ExpressionAttributeNames` - but in the wrong way.

When you define the "Item" to insert, you need to still use the full attribute name "index" - that's fine:

```
 Item={
        'index': entity.index,
        'invocationId': entity.invocationId,
        ...
    },
```

The word "index" in the item's definition was never the problem - the problem was (as the error message told you) that you used this word in an `ConditionExpression`. So you need to use this `#I` inside your `ConditionExpression`, and also pass `ExpressionAttributeNames` exactly like you did.

If you don't have a `ConditionExpression` (or some other expression) in your request, you don't need the `#I`, and not allowed to pass the unused `ExpressionAttributeNames`.